# mongoose updateOne function: don't update if $pull didn't work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm using `updateOne` method like this:

```
Photo.updateOne(
    {
        "_id": photoId
    },
    {
        "$pull": {
            comments: {
                _id: ObjectID(commentId),
                "user.id": user.id
            }
        },
        "$inc": { "commentCount": -1 },
    },
)
```

`Photo` model which contains comments as a array and `commentCount` as a number. When I run the code it's working but if the photo doesn't have the comment (which I'm trying to pull) it's still incrementing `commentCount` by `-1`. What I want is, if the code does not pull any comment in photo comments, don't update the `commentCount` too. How can I add this rule to my code?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I have updated my answer, added `$elemMatch` in query part, for making sure both the fields on comments are equal then it go to update part, in rare case this will happen otherwise my old one condition will also work because you are updating single document and using _id field almost time it will be unique for the particular parent document.

Comment: Its working great. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add both fields `comments._id` and `comments.use.id` conditions in query part, if comment is not available then it will skip update and pull part.

```
Photo.updateOne(
    { 
        _id: photoId,
        comments: {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id: ObjectID(commentId),
                "user.id": user.id
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$pull": {
            comments: {
                _id: ObjectID(commentId),
                "user.id": user.id
            }
        },
        "$inc": { "commentCount": -1 }
    }
)
```

Comment: You would need elemMatch to make sure the `comments._id` and `comments.user.id` are satisfied by the same comment.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your suggestion, i already tested without `$elemMatch`it is working perfectly. if you are saying to use in query part then by default update is providing array match using `.` dot, there is no need to use that operator, if you are saying to use in update(pull) part then it will not work because $elemMatch is only query and projection operator.

Comment: I'm saying that if one element in the comments array matches`"comments._id": ObjectID(commentId)` and a different element matches `"comments.user.id": user.id` it will satisfy the query part as you show here, but the `$pull` would not remove anything while the `$inc` modifies the count.  Using `$elemMatch` in the query part would prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature existing in Mongo, What you can do if you're using Mongo v4.2+ is use [pipelined update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), as the name suggests this gives you the power to use a pipeline within an update, hence allowing us to have conditions based on previous results.

```
Photo.updateOne(
    { "_id": photoId },
    [
        {
            $set: {
              comments: {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$comments",
                     as: "comment",
                     cond: {
                         $and: [
                           {$ne: ["$$comment._id", ObjectID(commentId)]},
                           {$ne: ["$$comment.user.id", user.id]} //really necessary?
                          ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                commentCount: {$size: "$comments"}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

For lesser versions you'll have to split it into 2 calls. no way around it.

-------------- EDIT ---------------

You can update the query to find the document using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), if it's not found then it means the comment belonged to someone else and you can throw an error in that case.

```
Photo.updateOne(
    { 
        _id: photoId,
        comments: {
           $elemMatch: {
               _id: objectID(commentId),
               "user.id": user.id
           }
        }
    },
    {
        "$pull": {
            comments: {
                _id: ObjectID(commentId),
                "user.id": user.id
            }
        },
        "$inc": { "commentCount": -1 }
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks for that answer but its not working well. I'm trying to do that because if user try to delete someone else's comment I want to return a error message. In your code ,if user try to delete another user's comment this will work because conditions are wrong. Assume like we have 2 different comment like {userId:1,commentId:1}, {userId:2,commentId:2} if one user who has the id value equals to 3  try to delete commentId=1 this will succesful because your code checks that condition commentId != 1 && userId != 3, this will return just second comment.

Comment: You can just check `modifiedCount` to see if the document was changed and then throw an error. Now that i understand your needs ill added in a simplified example using `$elemMatch`